# DFS using adjacent matrix fails

Tags: python, depth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

The code below is supposed to execute a DFS in a graph. I'm using adjacency matrices because of the performance. My pseudo algo is as follows:

1) pick a starting node `i`

2) add the node to `visited`

3) remove the node from `unvisited`

4) For each remaining node `j` in `unvisited`, check if there exists an edge `(i,j)` in the adjacency matrix, if yes, goto 1) and use `j` as a starting node.

I am using sets and not lists to keep track of visited/not visited because of the time complexity associated with lists (takes O(n) to remove from list but O(1) from sets).

The code fails given the simplest graph (n=3, [1,2],[2,3][1,2]). It returns an error.

```
File "solution.py", line 51, in dfs
    self.unvisited.remove(start)
KeyError: 2
```

How can I make this work?

Full code:

```
class GraphMat:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.size = n
        self.adjMat = [[False for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
        self.visited = set()
        self.unvisited = set([i for i in range(n)])
        self.path = []

    def allVisited(self):
        return len(self.unvisited) == 0

    def getFirstUnv(self):
        return next(iter(self.unvisited))

    def addEdge(self,u,v):
        self.adjMat[u-1][v-1] = True
        self.adjMat[v-1][u-1] = True

    def p(self):
        for i in self.adjMat:
            print i
        print '\n'

    def getUnvisited(self):
        return self.unvisited

    def dfs(self,start):
        print 'Visiting %d'%start

        self.path.append(start)
        print self.path
        self.visited.add(start)
        self.unvisited.remove(start)
        arr = [i for i in self.unvisited if self.adjMat[start][i]]
        print arr
        if len(arr) == 0:
            return
        for i in arr:
            self.dfs(i)

def main():
    g = GraphMat(3)
    for i in [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]:
        g.addEdge(i[0],i[1])
    g.dfs(0)


main()
```

Comment: Check whether start is in  unvisited.

Comment: This works great! However I am now running into the issue that for some cases it seems to return the wrong result. I don't see the specific input/output other that it's usually very large numbers (n<=10e5). Could this be the reason whz it fails?